# Uploads reported as too large on Knowledge Tree running on IIS 7 with PHP5

Tags: php, iis-7, upload

I am trying to upload a file from Knowledge Tree interface but for some odd reason it's displaying the following error message:

> The uploaded file is larger than the PHP upload_max_filesize setting

Currently I have it set to `-1` but it still won't upload the file successfully.

What needs to be done apart from changing the php.ini-dist and .htaccess properties?

Answer (score 0):

php.ini-dist isn't in use. You have to copy it to php.ini and then make modifications.

Also, are you really sure that you want unlimited file upload size?

Edit:

There are other variables that also controls how uploads (and PHP scripts in general) works:

upload_max_filesize > post_max_size > memory_limit

In human words: memory_limit must be larger than post_max_size, and post_max_size must be larger than upload_max_filesize.

Comment: Hi Pauska, thanks for your feedback.  I have copied php.ini-dist just as a backup and renamed the file to php.ini.  Modifications were already made previously.  This was to no avail as it's still not allowing me to upload a 7.30MB zipped file.  Do you have any idea what might be wrong?  Regarding the unlimited file upload size, that is just temporary.  I will change it to 20M once this works!

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: hey pauska.. many thanks for your help.. i was using the php.ini-dist, that was the problem, then I changed it from the php.ini located in windows and it's now working :)